# Get value by key from array of array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a meta as below:

```
obj = {
   meta: [['type', 'test1'], ['key2', 'value2']],
   value: 'text1',
}
```

Want to read value **test** by passing the key **type**

expected result is test1

Comment: Could you put your expected result here?

Comment: 'type' isn't a key. It's a member of an array of strings. Maybe you want to transform your data before you use it.

Comment: what happen if meta have more than two values ?

Comment: @AnhLe test should be the result

Comment: @jeremy-denis yes it will have, edited my question

Comment: How does the `value` property relate to your question?

Comment: @trincot I got answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

```js
const obj = {
   meta: [['type', 'test'], ['key2', 'value2']],
   value: 'text1',
}

const key = 'type'

const res = Object.fromEntries(obj.meta)[key];

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure meta as an object instead of an array of pairs as:

```js
obj = {
   meta: {
        'type': 'test',
        'key2': 'value2'
   }
   value: 'text1',
}
```

Now, you can access what you need as `obj['meta']['type']` or `obj.meta.type`.

Comment: meta is an array of arrays

Answer (score 0):

```js
obj = {
   meta: [['type', 'test'], ['key2', 'value2']],
   value: 'text1',
}

  for(let arr of obj.meta){
      if(arr[0]==='type'){
        return arr[1];
    }
 }
```

or

```js
const res=obj.meta.find(arr=>arr[0]==="type");
if(res && res.length) return res[1]
```

Notice that this code returns only the first "type". If you have "type" twice you'll get the first result.